# Spring Security problem starting Spring Boot application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I get this error when I try to start my Spring Boot application

```
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Receiver class org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method 'abstract void setServletContext(jakarta.servlet.ServletContext)' of interface org.springframework.web.context.ServletContextAware.
```

This is the pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.6</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>
    <groupId>bc.inv</groupId>
    <artifactId>inv-service</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>inv-service</name>
    <description>inv-service</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20230227</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>5.7.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

and this is the class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true, jsr250Enabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf()
                .disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/login", "/inv")
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .httpBasic()
                .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

I have tried changing the spring boot and spring security versions, but again the same problem. I am trying to understand what is the error, and then to finish the setup of this config class. Help!

Comment: Remove the spring security dependencies you added, remove the servlet-api dependency and only leave the `spring-boot-starter-security`. You currently are including jars/modules from different version of Spring Security (never mix jars from different versions) and the servlet api one is wrong for Spring Boot.

Comment: Thank you! I was trying to use older versions before and tried with WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter so I forgot about the other dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Clean and rebuild your project: Sometimes, cached or incompatible artifacts can cause issues. Clean your project's build and dependency caches, and rebuild it from scratch to ensure that you have a clean and consistent build environment.

Ensure compatibility with Jakarta Servlet API: The error message refers to the ServletContextAware interface from the Jakarta Servlet API. Verify that you have the correct version of the Jakarta Servlet API dependency. Make sure it aligns with your Spring Security and Spring Boot versions.

Verify Spring Security configuration: If you have a custom security configuration class, ensure that it extends **WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter** and overrides the necessary methods for configuring security. Check that you haven't accidentally overridden or modified the setServletContext method in your configuration.

Comment: WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter is deprecated, so I am trying to avoid it :)